# Angular + Laravel Delete File

Tags: angularjs, laravel, http

I'm building a REST-full web-app using Laravel 5.2 (for the back-end) and AngularJS for the font-end. I connect to the Laravel back-end by the use of an API. Now I have stumbled upon the following problem: I can properly upload an image, but deleting it again is not working.

The files are uploaded into the Larvel public/images/uploaded/ folder.
This is my Angular Service (the http request fired when clicking the 'delete' button) *where the variable imageToDelete is the relative path to the image.*. So Far so good, the request is firing and the imageToDelete variable is populated.

```
        function deleteProfileImage(imageToDelete) {
            return $http({
                method: 'DELETE',
                url: '/api/pictures/' + imageToDelete
            })
                .then(deleteProfileImageSuccess)
                .catch(deleteProfileImageError);

            function deleteProfileImageSuccess(response) {
                $log.info('Deleting profile picture Success.');
                console.log(response);
                return response;
            }

            function deleteProfileImageError(error) {
                $log.info('Deleting profile picture failed because: ' + error.data);
                return error;
            }
        }
```

This angular HTTP request fires a DELETE request to the following function in my Laravel Controller.

```
public function destroy($imageToDelete)
{
    if(Storage::delete($imageToDelete)) {
        return response()->json(['success' => 'success', 'message' => 'File Deleted']);
    } else {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Deleting Image failed.'])
            ->setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

**And here, the Storage::delete($imageToDelete) does nothing. It does not delete the file provided with the Angular DELETE request.**

Some things I have already tried:

Working with File::delete() instead of Storage::delete()
Working with unlink() instead op the Laravel Facades;
Sending the imageToDelete as data with the HTTP DELETE request (so not in the URL).
But all without success.

How can I make Laravel (PHP) delete the image?

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Not very clear what your specific problem is. See [ask]

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have updated my question. Hopefully it will be clear now.

Comment: No .... not really. A good question takes a bit of effort to properly explain first the problem as well as provide any troubleshooting details you can as well as explain what part is working and what's not

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$storage = Storage::find($imageToDelete);

if($storage->delete()) {
    return response()->json(['success' => 'success', 'message' => 'File   Deleted']);
}
```

or

```
 if(Storage::destroy($imageToDelete)) {
        return response()->json(['success' => 'success', 'message' => 'File Deleted']);
    }
```

or

```
 $deleteImage = Storage::where('id', $imageToDelete)->delete();
 if($deleteImage){
   return response()->json(['success' => 'success', 'message' => 'File Deleted']);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to check your image path. When you use laravel storage or file facde your file path should be absolute path for example `public_path($imageToDelete)`